# Dozer Boolean Mapping - Boolean Values

Tags: java, jaxb, spring-boot, jackson, dozer

I am exposing a service that consumes another SOAP service. I was provided with a JAXB generated model of the service. When I consume the service the data gets set into the objects pertinent to this model. I have defined my own domain model which has exactly the same set of classes as the JAXB model , but doesn't have the xml annotations etc. I am using dozer for performing the data mapping. When some of the boolean elements marked with annotation (nillable=true) are null , the destination object Boolean object in my domain model is set with default true or false value. I would like it to retain the same null value. The mapping and definition of boolean variables are listed below.

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.customer.types.CustomerPreferences
    </class-a>
    <class-b>com.customer.types.xml.CustomerPreferences
    </class-b>
    <field>
        <a is-accessible="true">isRequired</a>
        <b is-accessible="true">isRequired</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

JAXB Model

```
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable=true)
  protected java.lang.Boolean isRequired;
  // getters and setters
```

Domain Model

```
private Boolean isRequired;
//getters and setters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JAXB generates methods with "is" prefix for Boolean (object) properties but Dozer uses "is" prefix for primitive boolean types. "Is-accessible" Dozer mapping configuration property should solve the problem. But it seems for some reason it has not. You could try:

rename property in domain model by removing "is" prefix

rename getters and setter in domain model to get/set

use "get-method" Dozer mapping configuration property to define get method of JAXB model

use XJC plugin to fix get methods in JAXB model